# Why does MATLAB show a pole in bode plot of an underdamped second order system at natural frequency?

Tags: matlab, bode-plot, fourier, laplace-transform, frequency-response

I am using the sisotool in MATLAB to obtain the bode plot of the following transfer function:
[image]

MATLAB marks a pole at wo which is approximately 11.18

[image]

What is the meaning of this? How would you even show complex poles on a bode plot? I understand doing this for real poles since the roll off change is clearly defined at that frequency but why here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.- `sisotool` is now part of the Control System Designer app**

I mention this because the specific help page for just `sisotool` has been removed.

So with the **Control System Designer**, as it is now, The **Bode Editor window** has no markers, aka called curve tips, to glide along a given curve and read each value, as it is possible on any plot generated with command plot.

**2.- Generating transfer function with the Control System Designer**

type transfer function with function `tf` :

```
num=[1 1];
den=[1 20 125];
sys=tf(num,den)
sisotool(sys)
```

[image]

The default architecture for this transfer function is

[image]

among the ones available in the palette

[image]

**3.- No marker on curve**

no marker to directly read values, when one in need to read values rigth away.

So next thing one may do is to try export

[image]

This export generates 1 `ss` variable named `LoopTransfer_C` in the workspace

**4.- To the part of your question**

*How would you even show complex poles on a bode plot?*

I refer to Andy's concise answer in this same question, to visualize the Laplace transform MAPPING.

Sure thing you are going to like Andy's website under construction

http://stades.co.uk/index.html

Another useful website explaining how the Laplace transform works is **CONTROL**:

https://control.com/

In this website there is a concise analysis of basic tank circuits with Laplace transform showing how poles and zeros behave for different circuit configurations.

[image]

I have asked permission to reproduce this screenshot

https://control.com/textbook/ac-electricity/transfer-function-analysis/

**5.- Comments**

**To needbrainscratched :**

The complex does not work out to be at 5.08.

As I show in **point 8** the poles ARE, plural, 2 conjugate poles: `[-10+1j*5 -10-1j*5]`

**To TimWescott :**

**Control System Designer** is not picking a transition point (of the transfer function). It has picked the peak point of the amplitude.

The point chosen are the 2 coinciding (on real axis) poles, that are complex conjugate.

The most important graph is the top one: **AMPLITUDE** rules.

The 2nd one is the **PHASE**. The amplitude of the transfer function tells whether a signal get's through or not, regardless of whatever phase.

If the amplitude is null or too low, the phase value is useless.

**6.- There are other ways to get to the values of the poles:**

```
s=[0:.01:1e3];
G=125*(s+1)./(s.^2+20*s+125);

Gmag=abs(G);
Gph=angle(G);

figure
plot(s,Gmag);
grid on
grid minor
xlabel('s')
title('|H(s)| and s both linear')
```

[image]

```
figure
loglog(s,Gmag);
grid on
grid minor
xlabel('s');ylabel('dB')
title('|H(s)|dB and s both log plot ')
title('|H(s)|')
```

[image]

**7.- command `fsolve` ONLY returns the real part of the poles**

```
f1=@(x) x^2+20*x+125;
x0=fsolve(f1,0)
x0=fsolve(f1,5)
x0=fsolve(f1,-5)
```

fsove get's tuck on the real part and ignores the imaginary parts.

**8.- Calculating all poles, 1 line:**

So where are the poles

```
p1=pole(sys)

p1 =
-10.000000000000002 + 4.999999999999999i
-10.000000000000002 - 4.999999999999999i
```

**9.- `bode` and `bodeplot`**

These 2 are commands that have been included in the **Control System Designer** App but they still have a lot of punch as stand alone functions

```
figure
bode(sys)
grid on
```

[image]

read more about `bode` here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dynamicsystem.bode.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_bode

```
figure
bodeplot(sys)
grid on
```

produces same plot as `bode`

read more about bodeplot here

https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/dynamicsystem.bodeplot.html?searchHighlight=bodeplot&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_bodeplot

**10.- generating transfer function from zeros and poles with `zpk`**

```
z1=-1
p1=p1
g0=125
sys2=zpk(z1,p1,g0)

z1 =
    -1
p1 =
-10.000000000000002 + 4.999999999999999i
-10.000000000000002 - 4.999999999999999i
g0 =
   125

sys2 =
 
      125 (s+1)
  -----------------
  (s^2 + 20s + 125)
```

**10.- `H(s)` to `H(f)` Frequency Response**

```
f=[1:.001:1e3];   % [Hz]

H=125*(1j*2*pi*f+1)./((1j*2*pi*f).^2+20*(1j*2*pi*f)+125);
Hmag=abs(H);
Hph=angle(H);

figure
plot(f,Hmag);
grid on
grid minor
xlabel('f[Hz]')
title(' AMPLITUDE |H(f)| and both linear')
axis([0 200 0 6.8])
```

[image]

```
figure
% loglog(f,20*log10(Hmag));
loglog(f,(Hmag));
grid on
grid minor
xlabel('f[Hz]')
title('POWER |H(f)|^2 dB both axes log')
```

[image]

I added these points to support Andy's concise answer as the answer that solves this question.

Answer (score 1):

> *How would you even show complex poles on a bode plot?*

You can show a complex pole's \$j\omega\$ co-ordinate on the bode plot: -

[image]

I'm talking about \$\boxed{\omega_n\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}}\$ on the \$j\omega\$ axis.

Image from [my basic website](http://stades.co.uk/). Maybe you didn't realize that the \$j\omega\$ axis of a bode plot corresponds entirely with the \$j\omega\$ axis on the pole-zero diagram: -

[image]

Or, maybe they are showing the natural resonant frequency (indicated as \$\color{green}{\boxed{\omega_n}}\$ on my first picture) or the circle where it crosses the \$j\omega\$ axis in the picture directly above (after all \$\sqrt{125}\$ = 11.18034).

Comment: The complex pole works out to be 5.08 which is way off from 11.1803. Shouldn't they show the mark at 5.08 in this case? Is there any convention followed for showing poles on bode plots that I am not aware of?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Matlab function calls, but it looks like it's just picking out the midpoint of the transition from +20dB/decade to -20dB/decade.  What does that function's documentation say?

Comment: Then they are showing the natural resonant frequency and that is clearly 11.18 rad/s. I know nothing about Matlab (and I mean sweet FA). But, it struck me that knowing about Matlab wasn't a requirement for answering the question.

Comment: +1 for such nice website you are building at http://stades.co.uk/index.html